# Get the custom link type url that caused the app to open

Tags: android, ios, url-scheme

I would like to register a custom link type for my Android and iOS web apps, and then have the app do different things based on the URL that caused it to open.

For example, if the user clicks on `myurlscheme://item?1234`, then I want the app to open to the details page of "item 1234"

I think I can register my custom link types in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and `MyApp.plist` files respectively (just like for native apps), but how can I get access to the full URL in my JavaScript app code?